# How different are the industry jobs specific to Ph.D vs jobs where both Ph.D/MS are hired?

Tags: phd, job, industry, early-career

(I am not sure if this is an academia question. So feel free to flag/take it down if this is not the right forum to ask)

My question is specific to the context of Computer Science/Computer Engineering in the US. I assume industries hire graduate degree holders for positions where the degree requirement is:

- (1) MS or Ph.D, or
- (2) only Ph.D

Even with the second category (2) "Only Ph.D" I assume (again) there could be 2 types of jobs :

- (2.1) Research based roles
- (2.2) Engineering/development role with no research component.

My question is: What makes (2.2) special that it needs a Ph.D and so cannot be done with an MS?

Again, I could be over-simplifying things here and over-assuming (or even plain wrongly assuming), but since I haven't had such industry exposure, I am just very curious to understand how things work in the industry for Ph.D graduates.

Comment: Jobs in (2.2) aren't really in our wheelhouse; we are mostly researchers and/or instructors. You might try [workplace.SE], though you should read their rules before posting, you might need to rephrase. But moreover: do you have some examples of actual jobs in category 2.2, or are you just imagining that there might be jobs in this category? I would be surprised to learn that there are many such jobs in reality.

Comment: I am probably imagining (2.2), or just rewritten (1) as (2.2) , in which case (2.2) gets invalidated from even being a part of (2). I will post it in "The Workplace" and get back. I never knew a "The Workplace" stack exchange existed. Thanks!

Comment: Degree requirements are usually minimums. I hire masters and PhDs (I don’t do medical/bio so I’ve never seen an MD applicant) for R&D jobs from the same posting requirements. Do you meet the posting requirements? Apply, and make sure you highlight how you meet the desired attributes as well.